# slideDown effect issue

Tags: jquery

This Jquery works fine

```
$(row).hide().insertAfter($("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr")).fadeIn("slow");
```

This don't work

```
$(row).hide().insertAfter($("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr")).slideDown("slow");
```

Why a `slideDown` effect doesn't work ?

Comment: row is a html value...`<tr><td>test</td></tr>`

Comment: It can't slide down unless it has previously slided up. Whereas it can fade in if its opacity was set to 0 through CSS.

Comment: Is the row currently visible?

Comment: I think it can slideDown http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ look in demo. I need just hide the element

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck the row is not visible because I put the `.hide()`

Comment: You do know you are hiding the element inside the `row` variable, and sliding down the closest `tr` to that element. In other words you are hiding one element and sliding another. Try hiding the actual element you intend to slide!

Comment: @adeneo The `$(row)` is the variable that I will put after my closest `<TR>` so I hide my `$(row)` and insert this row after the closest `<TR>` with the `slideDown` effect in my row